# Может ли быть два двоеточия в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

> Куприн в своем рассказе «Гранатовый браслет» повествует именно об этом
> и оставляет читателям вопрос: так что же это: любовь или сумасшествие?

Answer (score 1):

Правила не запрещают двум двоеточиям находиться в одном предложении.
Но здесь расстояние между знаками малое, поэтому в этой конструкции — "пояснение пояснения" — вместо второго двоеточия вполне законно можно поставить тире.
Вот что о такой ситуации говорится в ПАС:

> **1.** Если несколько частей сложного предложения последовательно связаны значениями причины, пояснения (возможна подстановка союзов *потому что, а именно*), то, вопреки общему правилу (и в том и в другом случае правила предусматривают постановку двоеточия), возможна замена одного из двоеточий знаком тире для передачи разных оттенков значения. Ср. примеры: *Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось: из всех людей на
> свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська* (Пришв.). — *Было жалко Алпатову Гуська: с этим стариком связывалось всё лучшее в детстве и всегда казалось — из всех людей на свете нет лучше и нет роднее Гуська...* (двоеточие указывает на основное членение предложения, а тире является внутренним знаком).

*Куприн в своем рассказе «Гранатовый браслет» повествует именно об этом и оставляет читателям вопрос: **так что же это — любовь или сумасшествие?***

Так что же это ― клонирование, благо или опасная афера? [Алсу Разакова. Кто клон грядущий нам готовит // «100% здоровья», 2003.01.15]

[Взаимодействие знаков препинания в сложных конструкциях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144)

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендуется использовать два двоеточия в одном предложении. Возможна замена второго двоеточия тире.